# Python parse numbers and options with getopt

Tags: python, getopt

I am trying to add command line options to program. The program should accept both a list of numbers, and parse options. For instance a call to the program could look like:

```
python3 ./parsetest.py 4 3 v=100
```

The 4 and the 3 will be processed in one way whereas the v=100 command will set the internal variable v to 100. I found the getopt library is supposed to have this functionality: http://stackabuse.com/command-line-arguments-in-python/ Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

When I try to parse the input like the above, I believe getopt should place arguments which trigger its keywords into a special list, and those which do not trigger are placed elsewhere. However, when I try to use getopt following the example above, no matter what I do, the v=100 option does not appear to trigger the special arguments list. When passed to getopt, I expected the 'v=100' string to be split up into argument v and value 100. For instance, the print(arguments,values) command below results in: [] ['4', '3', 'v=100']. There are values, but there are no arguments.

Here is my code:

```
import sys,getopt
v = 1e100
fullCmdArguments = sys.argv
argumentList = fullCmdArguments[1:]
unixOptions = "v:"  
gnuOptions = ["v="]
print(argumentList)
try:  
  arguments, values = getopt.getopt(argumentList, unixOptions, gnuOptions)
except getopt.error as err:  
  # output error, and return with an error code
  print (str(err))
  sys.exit(2)

print(arguments, values)
for currentArgument, currentValue in arguments:  
  print (currentArgument, currentValue)
  if currentArgument in ("-v", "v"):
    v = currentValue
  else:
    #Its an integer then, do something with it
    print()
```

Comment: In regards to your question: "Is there a better/simpler way to do this?" `argparse` (also a built-in module) is pretty popular for command line argument parsing.

Comment: Is `getopt` a requirement, or could you also use `argparse`?

Comment: Note that your command line usage for options is non-standard: `v` is not an option, but `v=100` will be interpreted as a third argument. Perhaps you mean `python3 ./parsetest.py 4 3 -v=100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `argparse` the following will work:

### Example

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('numbers', type=int, nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-v', type=int, default=-1)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.numbers)
print(args.v)

# due to the default set above, `args.v` will always have an int value
v = args.v
```

Using the `nargs` keyword argument you can set it to '+' requiring one or more numbers. The `v` with a hyphen is by default optional. If this is not wanted, you can add the `required=True` option.

### Usage

```
python my_file.py 1 2 3 5 -v=12
[1, 2, 3, 5]
12

python my_file.py 1 2 3 5
[1, 2, 3, 5]
-1
```

### Further reading

For more information about the argparse module you can have a look at:

- The official tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html
- The module doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse